# Checkout UI Extension on Shopify app not updating value of textfield

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to set the value of the textfield component provided by checkout ui extesions on Shopify. I am receiving an error.

`ExtensionInteractionError: Error in ForwardRef() component event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  useExtensionApi,
  render,
  TextField,
} from '@shopify/checkout-ui-extensions-react';

render('Checkout::Dynamic::Render', () => <App />);

function App() {
  const { extensionPoint } = useExtensionApi();
  const [vatNumber, setVatNumber] = useState('');

  const handleVatNumberChange = (e) => {
    setVatNumber(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        label="VAT Number (Optional)"
        name="vat_number"
        value={vatNumber}
        onChange={(e) => handleVatNumberChange(e)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is no `e.target`. You just receive the new value of the field.

Comment: @FabioFilippi Thank you for your answer, that led me in the right direction. I actually hit another roadblock after getting past this, and I would really appreciate any insight you have. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538814/checkout-ui-extensions-does-not-populate-order-additional-details-on-shopify

Answer (score 0):

Change `e` to `value` and not using `e.target`

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  useExtensionApi,
  render,
  TextField,
} from '@shopify/checkout-ui-extensions-react';

render('Checkout::Dynamic::Render', () => <App />);

function App() {
  const { extensionPoint } = useExtensionApi();
  const [vatNumber, setVatNumber] = useState('');

  const handleVatNumberChange = (value) => {
    setVatNumber(value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        label="VAT Number (Optional)"
        name="vat_number"
        value={vatNumber}
        onChange={(value) => handleVatNumberChange(value)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```