# Checkout UI Extensions does not populate order additional details on Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have implemented a customization in the checkout process, and added a textfield. However, this textfield does not seem to be sending information over to the order details on Shopify. I'm wondering if it could possibly be that I'm using onChange wrong, if I'm setting the value incorrectly, or if I'm not supposed to use useState.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  useExtensionApi,
  render,
  TextField,
} from '@shopify/checkout-ui-extensions-react';

render('Checkout::Dynamic::Render', () => <App />);

function App() {
  const { extensionPoint } = useExtensionApi();
  const [vatNumber, setVatNumber] = useState('');

  const handleVatNumberChange = (val) => {
    setVatNumber(val)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        label="VAT Number (Optional)"
        name="vat_number"
        value={vatNumber}
        onChange={(val) => handleVatNumberChange(val)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This checkout API is quite new to me, but knowing how Shopify works, where do you expect the field? Maybe you need to create a metafield on the order?

Comment: @FabioFilippi I would expect it to appear under the additional details under the notes for the order. I have a store that is using checkout.liquid for these customizations currently, and that's where they appear. We're migrating to the new checkout UI extensions. 

If the fact is that I need to create a metafield for the order, can I no longer put it as an attribute in checkout.liquid, and I have to listen to the order created webhook, and send an API request?

This was our old code, and I'm assuming I'm missing something from it (maybe metafields), for the migration:

Comment: <div class="customer-ship-acct checkout-attributes field__input-wrapper"> \
      <label class="field__label field__label--visible" for="checkout_attribute_vat_number">VAT Number (optional)</label> \
      <input type="text" id="checkout_attribute_vat_number" class="checkout-attribute field__input" placeholder="VAT Number (optional)" name="checkout[attributes][vat_number]"';

Comment: yes that works because it uses `checkout[attributes][vat_number]` you should do something similar with your new code.

Comment: @A_Z Did you manage to do this?